# Threads in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Is it possible to use threads in bash scripts. I have a driver class in java that i'm trying to run multiple instances of at the same time. The only way i know to do this is make threads in bash, but i'm not sure if thats even possible. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you can run some stuff in the background using `&`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Bash doesn't support threading per se, but you could launch multiple java processes in the background, like:

```
java myprog &
java myprog &
java myprog &
```

Anything more than that you might look into Python or Ruby, which have thread management utilities, you could wait for each one to finish and collect output/exit status, etc.

**Edit**: Borrowing the suggestion from @CédricJulien to use `wait`, here's a more thorough example. Given this `MyProg.java` program:

```
public class MyProg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.exit(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
    }
}
```

you could write the following `bash-threads.sh` script to launch multiple instances of it in parallel:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit

java MyProg 1 &
pid1=$!
java MyProg 0 &
pid2=$!
java MyProg 2 &
pid3=$!

wait $pid1 && echo "pid1 exited normally" || echo "pid1 exited abnormally with status $?"
wait $pid2 && echo "pid2 exited normally" || echo "pid2 exited abnormally with status $?"
wait $pid3 && echo "pid3 exited normally" || echo "pid3 exited abnormally with status $?"
```

Its output is:

```
pid1 exited abnormally with status 1
pid2 exited normally
pid3 exited abnormally with status 2
```

Answer (score 50):

You won't be able to launch some "bash threads", but you can launch subprocesses in bash, just using the `&` after the command, and it will launch it in a background process.

Call a `wait` after launching your processes to wait for them to be finished.

Try this

```
first_command &
second_command &

wait
```

Comment: If I could check both of them I would. Both answers were perfect, but his was just before.

Answer (score 4):

Bash >= 4.0 supports the **coproc** keyword

coproc runs a command as though it was suffixed with & but allows access to it's process ID as well as stdin and stdout.

e.g.

```
coproc MYJOB myprog <args>
```

The process id of myprog is now $MYJOB_PID

An array variable $MYJOB then contains file descriptors for the job's stdout in $MYJOB[0] and stdin in $MYJOB[1]