# Python tail with grep

Tags: python, logging, tail, logrotate

Please help me. I have a log files, for example:
test_2014_03_13.log

i need tail it with grep and when created new file (test_2014_03_14.log) i need switch tailing with grep to a new file without skipping lines.

i need info about switching without skipping data.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What's your question in realizing your project?

Comment: i need info about switching without skipping data.

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703640/how-to-implement-a-pythonic-equivalent-of-tail-f

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you. I think you want to change the log file when a new one is created.

You need to run two different processes.

- The first one to search for changes in the directory so that you know when the new file was created, and then change it.
- The second process would be in charge of executing the "Tail+Grep", and when it is closed with the Kill instruction it should continue with the most recent file.

This is an example in Bash that you can easily write in Python. **I read too late that you were asking for an example in Python.**

```
#!/bin/bash

pidTail=0

inotifywait -m /var/log/yourfiles -e created |
while read path action file; do 
    echo “changed to $file”
    if [ ! $pidTail -eq 0 ]; then
        kill $pidTail
    fi
    tail -f $file | grep something >> newfile.log & 
    pidTail=$!
done
```

Note: I've written it right here and I haven't tested it, it may contain typos ;)

Even better late than never!

**Sources:**

[Threads in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156541/threads-in-bash)

[Script to monitor folder for new files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24952/script-to-monitor-folder-for-new-files)