# `read` command causes forked process to happen in foreground

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, qemu

Hello I am trying to write a bash script to launch QEMU in the background and wait for the user to press a key to continue with the script.

This is what I have currently:

```sh
setup_for_greengrass # these are functions
run_qemu & # fork function and try to run in the background
echo "Press anything to continue once VM is finished booting...\n"
read fullname # wait for user to press a key
install_greengrass
```

However, what I get in the terminal is the QEMU console and I am unable to keep moving forward with the script. If I fork the process and don't have the `read` command there, it works as expected and the QEMU console does not show up and the script keeps moving forward.

Any suggestions on how I could fork the QEMU process differently or wait for user input?

Comment: so run qemu without console?

Comment: @KamilCuk I would like to run qemu in the background so it does not block the rest of my script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... In bash version 4 or greater and zsh have support for this command called `coproc`.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/coproc-command-in-linux-with-examples/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68407430/4397021

https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2011/msg00095.html

So write the script as follows and it should launch the qemu in the background and let the script keep going forward.

```sh
#!/bin/zsh # Make sure to use zsh or upgrade your version of bash

setup_for_greengrass 
coproc run_qemu # launch qemu in the background 
echo "Press anything to continue once VM is finished booting...\n"
read fullname # wait for user to press a key
install_greengrass
```